# How to populate list view with three array?

Tags: java, android

I have three String[] populated with JSon data. So I need list view with all three String[] ,for example : String[] name to be on the top, then String[] address and on the bottom String[] phone. I found few tuts about custom array adapter but I didn't understand them so well. So, to repeat I already have all data in String[] name, String[] address and String[] phone just I need to put them in right adapter.
Can anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to have for example first listView item with name[0], address[0] and phone[0] and then next item?

Comment: Take a look at this Q and A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417806/android-in-which-way-should-i-separate-code-from-style/10418109#10418109 if you still have question notify me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you change the way you store your data to be a single array of a class that that you define with three `String` fields: `name`, `address`, and `phone`. Then the tutorials on using a custom adapter will be easier to adapt (so to speak). You'll just need to define a custom view for each row and have your adapter populate the view from the corresponding entry in the (single) data array.