# Listview alterations with a 30px bar above?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I was trying to find out if you could add a top bar to a `ListView`. Maybe 20-50 px in height with a couple of buttons(the buttons would also have to be click-able). Image to represent my idea:

[image]

The far left shot has a bar above the `ListView`, is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: yes, it looks like just a horizontal LinearLayout with some Buttons in it. Have you tried this already and had some trouble?

Comment: So you're saying there isn't a listview. Yes, I've tried this and it doesn't display, no error messages.

Comment: If you are referring to the left part of the image, that is the `ActionBar`(native or custom implemented).

Comment: The action bar Is not what I was referring to. I wanted to see if I could add a bar above a listview (in the image it's black).

Comment: Adding a bar to the top of a `ListView` is simple, you could do it with some layout modifications.

Comment: @TheBlueCat The Android terminology for "that black bar above the ListView" is an ActionBar.  In Android 3.0+ it's a native widget, prior to that we typically build them out of a `LinearLayout`.  You can very easily add one to your layout as Luksprog describes in his answer.  Android layouts can have many views in the hierarchy at the same time; ListView is just one of these widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your current layout so I assume that you have only a `ListView` element in a `LinearLayout`. Here is a `LinearLayout` with 3 `Buttons` at the top of the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any documentation I can read. I'm interested in this issue and would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I get an error when I try this code. " You must supply a resource Id for a textview". No, I don't have a textview in that code.

Comment: @TheBlueCat There is no documentation to recommend because the code above is a simple layout, you are limited by your goals(you could replace the `LinearLayout` full of `Buttons` with a `TableLayout` for example and add other views in a grid like layout). For example the black bar from your image is composed from 1 `TextView`(`layout_weight` 1) and 3 `ImageButtons` with drawable separators. There is a lot of documentation for the `ActionBar` if you want to read about it.

Comment: @TheBlueCat The layout above works for me so there is something in your code. Try cleaning the project and then running it again.

Comment: @TheBlueCat Are you supplying the right thing in the adapter's constructor? If you provide a layout file(containing other elements than a simple `TextView`) you should also pass the id of the `TextView` from the layout where you want your data to be put by the adapter.

Comment: `ListView lv = getListView();
        /* Gets a ListView */ 
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        
/* sorts the listview */ 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), com.gta5news.bananaphone.R.layout.chatservice, result.getheadlines());
        setListAdapter(adapter);` Is this ok?

Comment: @TheBlueCat If `R.layout.chatservice` contains more then a simple `TextView` tag(for example even if you enclose the `TextView` with `the LinearLayout`) then the adapter declaration should be: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), com.gta5news.bananaphone.R.layout.chatservice, R.id.id_of_textview_from_the_previous_layout, result.getheadlines());`

Comment: What do you mean? Id from a previous layout?

Comment: @TheBlueCat In `R.layout.chatservice` you have a `TextView`. Pass the `id` of that `TextView` in the adapter constructor.

Comment: I'm doing this `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), com.gta5news.bananaphone.R.layout.chatservice, com.gta5news.bananaphone.R.id.listView1,
          result.getheadlines());
        setListAdapter(adapter);` yet, it still crashes with the same log.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10917/discussion-between-luksprog-and-thebluecat)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
listView.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_view_divider));
```

list_view_divider should be a transparent png image with height you desire.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try that out, how could I implement a onClickListener? Say: id.getDrawable(); id.setonClickListener?

Comment: I have answered this question a few days ago. Look at this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417806/android-in-which-way-should-i-separate-code-from-style/10418109#10418109

Comment: That answer is about SQLLite? How does that come into play with my question? Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434758/how-can-i-make-the-my-listview-interactive/10434885#10434885